# What is the music playing in the background of the fight scene in episode 7?

Tags: music, ghost-in-the-shell-sac

In [Episode 7](http://youtu.be/gZWaYQVOVG03t=11m30s), around 11:30, what's the music playing in the background during the fight scene?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's "run rabbit junk" by Yoko Kanno from the first OST.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXSgnsnu8ro